# Protractor- in same page how to switch from non angular to angular, its clicking on non angular elements but not on angular?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, angular

In the same page how to switch from non-angular to angular,
it is clicking on non-angular elements but not on angular,
when clicking on non-angular lookup then angular window(Popup) will open

Comment: What's the error and relevant html source?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly. The solution is:

`browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` - for disabling Angular
`browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` - for enabling Angular

Then switch to the new window and search the angular element.

Comment: Your definition seems incorrect or incomplete. The method you referenced doesn't disable Angular but it does change how Protractor works/waits for different applications to finish loading.

Comment: It’s referenced to official documentation from Protractor. It says If you need to navigate to a page which does not use Angular, you can turn off waiting for Angular by setting browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false).

Comment: I agree with the explanation in your comment but it's inconsistent with your original answer. Sorry for the pedantry.